# Sending Data From Nodejs to Python

Tags: python, node.js

I have tested multiple node packages and tutorials trying to communicate between node and python, but have not had any success. Below is a simple node application streaming data:

(found at https://polygon.io/docs/#getting-started)

```
const NATS = require('nats')
const SERVERS = [
    'nats://nats1.polygon.io:30401',
    'nats://nats2.polygon.io:30402',
    'nats://nats3.polygon.io:30403'
]

// Connect to Polygon NATS cluster:
const nats = NATS.connect({
    servers: SERVERS,
    token: 'YourAPIKeyHere'
})

// Subscribing to Currency/FOREX Data...
nats.subscribe('C.*', (msg, reply, subject) => {
    let forex = JSON.parse( msg )
    //console.log('FOREX:', JSON.stringify( forex, null, 4 ))
    console.log(forex)
})
```

The code above works as long as you have node and installed 'nats' with npm.

My question is how I can efficiently get a running python script to pull in the data being output (in this case is is the variable 'forex').

Basically, instead of logging the data to the console, I want to be able to get the data and make use of it in a python script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/polygon-io/client-examples

Has client examples for real-time market data streams. Python is on there, that may solve your problem without having to use nodejs at all.